# Find an orthonormal basis of $ \mathbb{C^2} $ consisting of eigenvectors of $ T $

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gram-schmidt

**Question:**

Let $ r \in \mathbb{R} $ and let $ T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}) $ be the linear map with canonical matrix
$$
T =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & r \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Given this matrix, find an orthonormal basis of $ \mathbb{C^2} $ consisting of eigenvectors of $ T $

**Approach:**

I found the eigenvalues of $ T $ which came out to be

$$ \lambda = \frac{1 + r \pm \sqrt{r^2 -2r + 5}}{2} $$

The eigenvectors I found came out to be

$$ v_1 = (1, \frac{1 - r- \sqrt{r^2 -2r + 5}}{2}), v_2 = (1, \frac{1 - r + \sqrt{r^2 -2r + 5}}{2}) $$

At this point I'd like to apply Gram-Schmidt however, the computation of the length of each vector is quite large:

$$ g_1 = \frac{(1, \frac{1 - r- \sqrt{r^2 -2r + 5}}{2})}{||(1, \frac{1 - r- \sqrt{r^2 -2r + 5}}{2})||} $$
$$ ||(1, \frac{1 - r- \sqrt{r^2 -2r + 5}}{2})|| = \sqrt{1 \cdot 1 + \frac{1 - r- \sqrt{r^2 -2r + 5}}{2}) \cdot \overline{\frac{1 - r- \sqrt{r^2 -2r + 5}}{2})}}$$

In particular, I'm not sure what to do with the conjugate within the square root to simplify the process since there isn't going to necessarily be a complex component if $ r^2 -2r + 5 > 0 $

Thanks!

Comment: Since everything is real, you can simply disregard the conjugate.  You don't need Gram-Schmidt.  Observe that $T$ is real-symmetric (in fact a normal matrix suffices), eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal, so you get orthogonality for *free*.

Comment: Since $r^2-2r+5$ doesn’t have any real roots it is in fact positive for all $r$.